# how to modify object which is not in the same thread

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I am working on a async web request. and need to depends on the response to do a message return.

was thinking to do sth like following

```
// creating request

string messageToReturn = string.empty;
request.BeginGetResponse(ar => 
            { 
                HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState; 
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.EndGetResponse(ar);

                // is it safe to do this?
                messageToReturn = "base on respone, assign different message"; 


            }, request);

// will i get any response message? i will always get empty right?
// since response is handle in another thread
return messageToReturn;
```

what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, that variable will always be empty because you fired off an asyncronous request with the `BeginGetResponse` method.  So really you have a few options here.  You can either block the executing thread until the response comes back (probably a really bad idea unless you have a very strong argument for doing this), or you could use an event based asynchronous pattern to alert callers when your response returns...

Consider some of your code wrapped in a method

```
public void GetMessageAsync()
{
    string messageToReturn = string.empty;
    request.BeginGetResponse(ar => 
            { 
                HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState; 
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.EndGetResponse(ar);

                // is it safe to do this?
                messageToReturn = "base on respone, assign different message"; 


            }, request);
}
```

To wire up an event based pattern here.  We define a custom `EventArgs` class and a custom event which callers can listen for and which we will fire when the response comes back.

```
public class StringEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public string Message { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> MessageReturned;

public void GetMessageAsync()
{
    //string messageToReturn = string.empty;
    request.BeginGetResponse(ar => 
            { 
                HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState; 
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)req2.EndGetResponse(ar);

                //messageToReturn = "base on respone, assign different message"; 
                this.MessageReturned(this, new StringEventArgs { Message = response.ToString() });

            }, request);
}
```

Comment: thx for the reply... do you think i can just do this:  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { messateToReturn = ""something"; });

Comment: No, because even that method will execute asynchronously and it won't be guaranteed that the call will be complete when you return messageToReturn.  If you really want to block the thread until the response is back, check out ManualResetEvent.  Proceed with caution though!  Because it will lock up your UI.